# Saving Original File Name in Django with FileField

Tags: django, upload, filenames

```
def generate_uuid_file_name(self, filename):
    self.original_filename = filename
    extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
    newfilename = uuid.uuid4().__str__() + '.' + extension
    return self.directory() + newfilename

class FileUpload(models.Model):
    original_filename  = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    fileobj            = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_uuid_file_name)
```

On upload,

```
{"errors": {"original_filename": ["This field is required."]}, "success": false}
```

Adding blank=True, null=True to the FileUpload.original_filename allows the upload to succeed but does not save the original file name. On Django 1.5. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905674/django-how-to-save-original-filename-in-filefield), this should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do that in the view (after null=True, blank=True are again part of your model):

```
file_object = UploadFileForm.save(commit=False)
file_object.original_filename = request.FILES['file'].name
file_object.save()
```

Mind that you will need to change the above code accordingly with your context etc

Comment: So, that totally worked. However, I'm still a little confused as to why the self.original_filename above didn't ?? My understanding is that it's passed by reference so the original code should have worked ?

Comment: If the `original_filename` field was before the `fileobj` field, it would work.

Comment: Man, I love django.

Comment: If your model has a many-to-many relationship with another model you should use `file_object.save_m2m()` in the end of the suggested code.