# Keeping Original Filename for FileField in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

I would like to keep the original file name of an `UploadedFile` in Django that has its location stored in a `FileField`. Right now I am observing that if two files have the same name, the first file uploaded keeps its original name but the second time a file with that name is uploaded, it has a random string appended to make the file name unique. One solution is to add an additional field to the model: [Django: How to save original filename in FileField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905674/django-how-to-save-original-filename-in-filefield) or [Saving Original File Name in Django with FileField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355888/saving-original-file-name-in-django-with-filefield) but these solutions seem suboptimal as they require changing the `Model` fields.

An alternative would be to prepend a random directory path to the front of the file make sure that in a given directory the file name is unique and allowing the `basename` to remain unchanged. One way to do this would be to pass in a callable `upload_to` that does just that. Another option would be to subclass `FileField` and override `get_filename` to not strip the input filename to the `basename` allowing the caller to pass in a filename with a prepended path. The latter option is not ideal if I want to use an `ImageField` as I would have to subclass that as well.

Answer (score 2):

In looking at [the code that actually generates the unique filename by appending the random string](https://github.com/django/django/blob/53ff0969822ac2248a89ccb6fef1088212dc800d/django/core/files/storage.py#L65), it looks like the best solution to this problem might be to [subclass the `Storage` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/) in-use and [override `get_available_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/#django.core.files.storage.get_available_name) method to create unique filenames by prepending a directory rather than post-pending the string to the base name.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the quick answere, here is another approach to your question :
The idea here is to create an unique folder for each uploaded file.

```
# in your settings.py file
MY_FILE_PATH = 'stored_files/'
```

The path were your files will be stored : **/public/media/stored_files**

```
# somewhere in your project create an utils.py file
import random
try:
    from hashlib import sha1 as sha_constructor
except ImportError:
    from django.utils.hashcompat import sha_constructor


def generate_sha1(string, salt=None):
    """
    Generates a sha1 hash for supplied string.

    :param string:
        The string that needs to be encrypted.

    :param salt:
        Optionally define your own salt. If none is supplied, will use a random
        string of 5 characters.

    :return: Tuple containing the salt and hash.

    """
    if not isinstance(string, (str, unicode)):
         string = str(string)
    if isinstance(string, unicode):
        string = string.encode("utf-8")
    if not salt:
        salt = sha_constructor(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
    hash = sha_constructor(salt+string).hexdigest()

    return (salt, hash)
```

In your models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from utils.py import generate_sha1

def upload_to_unqiue_folder(instance, filename):
    """
    Uploads a file to an unique generated Path to keep the original filename
    """

    salt, hash = generate_sha1('{}{}'.format(filename, get_datetime_now().now))

    return '%(path)s%(hash_path)s%(filename)s' % {'path': settings.MY_FILE_PATH,
                                               'hash_path': hash[:10],
                                               'filename': filename}



#And then add in your model fileField the uplaod_to function
class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to_unique_folder)
```

The file will be uploaded to this location :

**public/media/stored_file_path/unique_hash_folder/my_file.extention**

Note : I got the code from [Django userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena) sources, and adapted it to my needs

Note2 : For more informations take a look at this greate post on Django File upload : [File upload example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871730/need-a-minimal-django-file-upload-example)

Have a good day.

Edit : Trying to provide a working solution :)

Comment: This will only work if two files with the same name are not uploading on the same date.

Comment: Edited my answere with an other solution for your case, didn't tested it, but it should work

Answer (score -2):

To my understanding, during the form submission/file upload process, you can add form validation functions.

During the validation and cleaning process, you could check that the database does not already have a duplicate name (ie. query to see if that file name exists).

If it is duplicate, you could just rename it xyz_1, xyz_2, etc

Comment: see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) for reference

Comment: The issue is this is appending a string to the name. I would have to strip it off on serving it back up. Also how do I know if the first file already ended with an underscore and then a number? I would have to escape too.

Comment: you could for example prepend or append a time stamp to the file name (eg: xyz_20140101121259). a time stamp that goes down to the milliseconds, and u know exactly the length of this time stamp, so it will be easy to strip it out when you serve it back up

Comment: This is good almost all of the time, but again there is no guarantee that two files won't be uploaded in the same millisecond.

Comment: if you are so worried about that then do 20140101121259001, 20140101121259002 etc.